# Retrieve text field from form

Tags: django, django-forms

I am learning Django 1.6 and got stuck in the forms part...

I have basically one view and one template which is a form with one text field and once this form is sent, it would return the same view but with the results listing below

I have it already done but could not put the form to work...

What I am trying to do is to get the value from a form field into a view and filter the view records based on this value.

I have this form in a template

```
<form id="1"  method="post" action="/search/">
<label class="description" for="element_3">Brand</label>
<input id="element_3" name="brand" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/>
```

which is calling this view

```
def index(request):
    latest_products = products.objects.filter(brand='adidas', )
    template = loader.get_template('search/index.html')
    context = {'latest_products': latest_products}
    return render(request, 'search/index.html', context)
```

What should I do to retrieve the value of the field 'brand' from my form to use as a search filter?

Comment: I would recommend going through the django [hello world](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/), it touched on a lot of these basics. Here's a link to the forms docs, your question is covered there: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request object has a field named method.  You can test request like so:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    [process data]
```

request.POST is a dictionary which should have the form's input names with associated values.

You also might want to look at Django Forms

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/

Good luck!